# C# Aforge MJPEG stream motiondetection

Tags: c#, stream, aforge, mjpeg

I am still new at programming, I code as a hobby :)

I wanted to make a MJPEG streaming aplication with an option to record a video and save it on computer when it detects a moving. So far i've managed to get stream to videosourceplayer in WPF, but it seems that i can't manage to get the information whether moving is detected or not. What am i doing wrong? i've tried many things ( commented ). but it seems that i can't compare float MotionDetected to limited (in my case 0.02). my label5 simply doesnt change.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Vision.Motion;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using System.Globalization;
using AForge.Controls;

namespace AnotherAForge
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MotionDetector Detector;
        float f;
        float MotionDetected;
        int frames;
        private VideoFileWriter _writer;
        private MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream("link to the cam i can't share");
        int uporabimotiondetection = 0;

        private IVideoSource _videoSource;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        Form form1 = new Form();

        public void videoSourcePlayer1_NewFrame(object sender, ref Bitmap image)
        {
            if (uporabimotiondetection == 1)
            {
                MotionDetected = Detector.ProcessFrame(image);

                //if (label5.InvokeRequired) {
                //    label5.Text = NivelDeDeteccion.ToString();
                //}
                //if (Detector.ProcessFrame(image) > 0.02)
                //{
                //    label5.Text = "1";
                //}
            }
            frames++;      
        }

        private void alarm() {
            label2.Text = MotionDetected.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //VideoStream.NewFrame += VideoStream_NewFrame;
            //VideoStream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(ProcessNewFrame);

            stream.Start();

            //stream.NewFrame += Stream_NewFrame;
            //videoSourcePlayer1.NewFrame += videoSourcePlayer1_NewFrame;
            videoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = stream;

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Start();
            //pictureBox1.Image = image;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Detector = new MotionDetector(new TwoFramesDifferenceDetector(),new MotionAreaHighlighting());
            MotionDetected = 0;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           // textBox1.Text = NivelDeDeteccion.ToString();
            label3.Text = frames.ToString() + " frames";
            label2.Text = MotionDetected.ToString();

            if (MotionDetected <= 0.02 && MotionDetected >= 0)
            {
                label5.Text = "1";
            }
            else {
                label5.Text = "0";
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        int time;
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time++;
            label4.Text = time.ToString();   
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            stream.Stop();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stream.Stop();
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                uporabimotiondetection = 1;
            }
            else {
                uporabimotiondetection = 0;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00000}", textBox1.Text);

            //float motionlevel = float.Parse(MotionDetected);

            //float a = 1;
            //textBox2.Text = a.ToString();

            //float b = MotionDetected / 100;
            //textBox1.Text = b.ToString();

            //double limiter = Convert.ToDouble("0,02");
            //textBox2.Text = limiter.ToString();

            //if (MotionDetected < (0.02f / 1000))
            //{
            //    label5.Text = "gibanje";
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    label5.Text = "ni gibanja!";
            //}
        }
    }
}
```